# How to validate purchase with date in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want have function that validating a purchase by date. The Scenario like.
 1. We get the date from computer.
 2. we do check, if the current date is the day after the purchase date. The purchase will be expired and deleted automatically from the table.

i get the code, but not working well.

```
public void validasiPembayaran() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT tglBeli FROM membeli";
        java.sql.Connection conn = ((Connection) Config.configDB());
        java.sql.Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(sql);      
        String status = "Tertunda";
        while (res.next()) {    
            if (getTanggal().equals(res.getString("tglBeli")) || res.getString("statusPembelian").equalsIgnoreCase("Lunas")) {
                System.out.println("tanggal sama atau lunas");
            } else {
                String sql2 ="DELETE FROM membeli WHERE statusPembelian = '"+status+"'";
                java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
                pst.execute();
            }
        }            
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: "Not working well" isn't an error message or problem statement. Please be specific about what is going wrong, and what you expected the code to do instead. And give suitable information based on your debugging so far. Also provide sample data if relevant, to allow people to reproduce the exact scenario.

Comment: You can use Java8- local.dateandtime, check its APIs they do many operations

Comment: The code shown has nothing to do with dates. Voting to close as unclear. There is no discernible question to be answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
string formatedDate = dtf.format(now);
```

Let compare formatedDate to date you have got in database table.